# ColdFusion or PHP Shopping script

Tags: php, mysql, coldfusion

Hello what I want to do is include a shopping cart on CF site.  There are only 10 products but they want it to have their same look.   Is there a way to have an include that would render a mini shopping cart inside their pages, but use outside shopping cart program.

I'm not sure if there is anything like this so any suggestions would be helpful.

I can use any of the following technologies.
PHP 
MYSQL
CF

I was hoping there is a solution like popshops.com for Shopping carts.  Where the backend is managed somewhere else and I just put a script embeding it on my site.

Comment: ha - funny. Its cuz everytime I ask a question on this site I forget to login and then have to repost it.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: wow coldfusion and php tags in the same post. what is the world coming too!?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured out the answer.  I am just using google store checkout.  It lets you creat products and then embed them in your own site rather easily.  Thanks everyone.

Google_Checkout_Store
http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Store_Gadget_How_To.html

Answer (score 0):

[CF Shopkart](http://www.cfshopkart.com/) looks promising... and free as in beer!

[CF Webstore](http://www.cfwebstore.com/), [CF Ezcart](http://www.cf-ezcart.com/) are also ready made CFML solutions.

[Cartweaver](http://www.cartweaver.com/) also might be worth looking at, it works for both PHP and CFML

Answer (score 0):

List of CF shopping carts: http://www.carehart.org/cf411/#ecm